# Unable to see isomorphism between $U_8$ and $\mathbb{Z}_8$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

$U_8$ is isomorphic with $\mathbb{Z}_8$ in which $a = e^{i2\pi/8} \leftrightarrow 5$. Under this isomorphism, we must then have $a^2 = a * a \leftrightarrow 5 +_8 5 = 2$.

I just don't see it. $a^2 = i \neq 2$. How is it isomorphic?

Furthermore, I don't think I understand Isomorphism. I suppose from the standpoint that there is a one-to-one correspondence, then fine, but other than that, I thought isomorphism were algebraic structures on different sets that output the same answer.

Comment: Huh? $U(8)=({\Bbb Z}/8{\Bbb Z})^\times$ and ${\Bbb Z}/8{\Bbb Z}$ are definitely **not** isomorphic. Perhaps you are using the letters $U$ and $Z$ in some nonstandard way - if so please clarify. Also, what might "output the same answer" mean? Edit: reading Cameron's answer, it seems by $U_8$ you are referring to the group generated by $e^{2\pi i/8}$ under multiplication. | You say "I suppose .. there is a one-to-one correspondence, then fine" but then you wonder why elements of one group are not equal to another. "Correspondence" does not mean things in one set *equal* things in another set...

Answer (score 1):

All that you need to prove it is an isomorphism is to show that $5$ generates $\Bbb Z_8$.

As for your confusion: of course the complex number $i$ isn't an equivalence class of the integers. The point is that the multiplicative group consisting of $8$ particular complex numbers acts "the same as" the additive cyclic group of integers *modulo* $8$.

Comment: So the essence is that by using multiplication starting with one of the 8 particular complex numbers, I could make generate the entire set of 8? Just like I can generate the set of 8 integers in the additive cyclic group?

Comment: Pretty much, yeah. You've got to choose your starting point a bit carefully (only $4$ in each group will be generators), but that's the gist, when working with cyclic groups.

Comment: I edited my question and put at the bottom what I originally thought isomorphism was. Is there a better or more correct way to think about it?

Comment: More generally, if you've got groups $G,H$ with operations $*,\#,$ then an isomorphism between $G$ and $H$ is a one-to-one correspondence $f:G\to H$ such that $f(x*y)=f(x)\#f(y)$ for all $x,y\in G$. The idea is that the operation in one "acts the same" as the operation in the other, as far as the function is concerned.

Comment: Ah, I see. Would this work? From $(\mathbb{R}^+, \times)$ to $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ through $\log_b(xy) = \log_b(x) + \log_b(y)$?

Comment: Indeed, it would! Bravo!

Comment: Interesting. So if we found all the one-to-one correspondence between $U_8$ and $\mathbb{Z}_8$, and we knew we got the one-to-one correspondence through the multiplicative group of $U_8$ and the additive group of $\mathbb{Z}_8$, then there exists a function that could take us from $U_8$ to $\mathbb{Z}_8$ (like $\log$ did above). Furthermore, if we knew the correspondence and were interested in $\mathbb{Z}_8$, but the math was easier in $U_8$, then we could do our computations there, and then simply go through the correspondence to get our answer in the other algebraic structure, correct?

Comment: To an extent, you're correct--in fact, that very thing is why slide rules and logarithm tables were used, to simplify multiplication--but a one-to-one correspondence isn't enough on its own. For example, the [quaternion group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group) also has 8 elements, so can be put into one-to-one correspondence with $\Bbb Z_8,$ but it isn't a commutative group, much less a cyclic group, so is *not* isomorphic with $\Bbb Z_8$.